# Angular custom validation unique set value $digest already in progress

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This post is a step forward  of 
[angular custom validation unique email trigger once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015292/angular-custom-validation-unique-email-trigger-once/19028003)

so with the code in the old post i realized that the value of the field email
(when I send to the server) is undefined so I tried like

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <form novalidate id="frm-signup" name="addContestantFrm" data-ng-submit="add()">
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email: *</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input-medium" tabindex="3" title="email" maxlength="255" value="{{contestant.email}}" placeholder="email" data-ng-model="contestant.email" required email-unique />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" id="sbmt" name="sbmt" class="input-sbt" data-ng-disabled="!addContestantFrm.$valid" value="Send" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.factory('Contestant',function($http){
                return {
                    checkUniqueEmail : function(email){
                        return $http.post('./checkemail.php',{email:email});
                    }
                }
            });
            app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
                $scope.add = function(){
                    console.log($scope.contestant);
                }
            });
            app.directive('emailUnique',function(Contestant) {
                return {
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs,ctrl) {
                        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                            console.log(ctrl.$error.email);
                            Contestant.checkUniqueEmail(viewValue).success(function (response) {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('emailUnique', true);
                                scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                                    ctrl.$setViewValue('email', viewValue);
                                });
                                return viewValue;
                            })
                            .error(function (data) {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('emailUnique', false);
                                console.log(viewValue);
                                return undefined;
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

give me 
**$digest already in progress**

so how is the way to set the email value to send to the server (now there is just an example)

**Update**

I tried with if

```
(!scope.$$phase) {
  //never excuted
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS custom form validation using $http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810913/angularjs-custom-form-validation-using-http)

Comment: I wrote a directive to take care of this functionality and any similar circumstance. Check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25678196/1435655

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `$http` kicks off a `$digest` cycle, and then `.$apply` from the `scope` is trying to kick off another one. You should just be able to set the `scope` variable and see it reflected, or possibly try returning all of the promises with `.then`

```
Contestant.checkUniqueEmail(viewValue).success(function (response) { //<- Digest started
    ctrl.$setValidity('emailUnique', true);
    /*
    scope.$apply(function(scope) { //<--Trying to start again
        ctrl.$setViewValue('email', viewValue);
    });
    */
    return viewValue;
})
```

Using `.then`

```
checkUniqueEmail : function(email){
    return $http.post('./checkemail.php',{email:email}).then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });
}

Contestant.checkUniqueEmail(viewValue).then(function (response) {
    //try stuff here now.
});
```

Comment: Thanks tymeJV I updated the code a gist https://gist.github.com/whisher/6714864 but it still give me undefined :( (and with apply the same error)

Answer (score 0):

timeJV was right , the problem was coming from the http post promise handling.
It must be done with this pattern

```
var deferred=$q.defer() 
http.post(...).success(...).error(...);
return defered.promise
```

I created a jsfiddle from your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dirakkk/jttmtdvq/) and did some modification so that it works.

Please do tell me if you need something else

Comment: That's the promise anti-pattern and should never be used.