# Angular directive for unique username

Tags: angularjs

I looked at a bunch of angularjs directives checking for uniqueness of a username and decided to try for the simplest implementation. It does what I want but may not really be 'idiomatic' angular.  Here is the form element:

```
<input type="text"
    name="username"
    ng-model="form.username"
    unique-username=""
    required
/>
<span class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="thisform.username.$error.unique">Username taken!</span>
```

and here's the directive:

```
.directive('uniqueUsername', function($http) {
      return {
           restrict: 'A',
           require: 'ngModel',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.bind('blur', function (e) {
                     ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);

                     $http.get("/api/checkUnique/" + element.val()).success(function(data) {
                          if (data) {
                              ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
                          }
                     });
                });
           }
      };
})
```

And the expressjs call

```
if (data) {
      console.log("found " + data.username);
      return res.send(data.username);
}
else {
      console.log("not found");
      return res.send(404);
}
```

I would appreciate any feedback on why this is good or bad and if possible a revision that uses $scope.watch on the model.

Comment: See this post for my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25678196/1435655

Answer (score 2):

One small improvement - I would recommend adding a $loading flag. Since it is an asynchronous request, it make take time for it to return:

```
directive('uniqueUsername', function($http) {
      return {
           restrict: 'A',
           require: 'ngModel,^form',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.bind('blur', function (e) {
                     ngModel.$loading = true;

                     $http.get("/api/checkUnique/" + element.val()).success(function(data) {
                        ngModel.$loading = false;
                        ngModel.$setValidity('unique', !data);
                     });
                });
           }
      };
})
```

Then you can show a wait message (or spinner) while its waiting for the async call to return:

```
<input type="text"
    name="username"
    ng-model="form.username"
    unique-username=""
    required
/>
<span ng-show="thisform.username.$loading">Loading...</span>
<span class="hide-while-in-focus" 
     ng-show="thisform.username.$error.unique">Username taken!</span>
```

If you want it to stop form submission until the async call returns, then I would suggest making $loading a validity flag (i.e. $setValidity('loading', true/false))