# How can I check to see if a username is already used with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my form I have a username field that is user for registration. I would like to make this trigger an error message on the field. Something like the error message I would get if I did not enter a value on a field with ng-required.

Can someone tell me how I can make it so that when a user leaves the field then an HTTP request is sent to the database to check for an existing username and then if present an error condition is set for that field.

I am not really looking for specific HTTP request code but just even some pointers would be a big help.

Comment: You can use the ngBlur directive to get the blur event. In your controller define a function which checks whether the user is existent in your backend or not.

Comment: If you are on 1.3 check http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html, specifically async validator part.

Comment: For older version this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866040/angular-directive-for-unique-username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-7-%E2%80%93-creating-a-unique-value-directive-using-asyncvalidators) a nice guide on how to check a name field using custom directive and new features from 1.3