# How to check name uniqueness in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, unique

I want to check whether the prefix is unique or not while user is filling the form for that i have followed

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HojHE3ndnZeugGzZugWs?p=preview)**

In my code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : course_form.prefix.$invalid && (!course_form.prefix.$pristine || submitted) }">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <label for="prefix">Prefix</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
      <input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       id="prefix"
       placeholder="Prefix ( eg: FIN )"
       data-ng-model="courses.single.prefix"
       required name="prefix"
       name-unique="prefix"
       >
   </div>
   <div class="help-block col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-9 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9" ng-show="course_form.prefix.$invalid && (!course_form.prefix.$pristine || submitted)"> Prefix is required. 
   </div>
</div>
```

How can i use name-unique properly in my code so that i can validate the prefix properly?

Comment: properly in what sense.....the plunker is working properly with validation, apart from that what's you think you want to achieve

Comment: I didn't know how to integrate

Comment: :) where and what to integrate ......., i am not getting actually

Comment: A nice directive for asynchronous ($http/ajax) validation has to tackle several issues. I think I came up with something nice and have unit tests to verify it is working well. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25678196/1435655

Answer (score 0):

The value of name-unique must be in the url you are matching. Because of:

```
var Model = $resource("/api/" + attrs.nameUnique
```

For the tests, they should be like:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/prefix?name=bar').respond([users[1]]);
```

Does this help?